# On the Distribution of Points on a Sphere

Tags: geometry, analysis

Given $n$ points distributed on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$, I want to come up with an expression which maximizes the minimum pairwise distance between 2 points. I think the expression could be based on just $n$. Let's assume the $n$ data points are $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for $1 \le i \le n$. Let's define $K$
$$K = \sup_{x} \left [ \min_{1 \le i < j \le n} \Vert x_i - x_j\Vert \right]$$

My idea here, based on the picture in $\mathbb{R}^2$. There is a naturally optimal distribution of the points which maximizes $K$.

[image: probleminr2]

In this case the optimal distribution is represented by regular polygons. The regular polygons have vertices that are equally spaced on the sphere. For the regular polygons I am claiming that $\min_{1 \le i < j \le n} \Vert x_i - x_j\Vert = K$. The proof would say: if you had some polygon with the corners not equally spaced, then the $\min_{1 \le i < j \le n} \Vert x_i - x_j\Vert$ would be less than $K$, which is represented by the regular polygon.

I'm fairly certain about this in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but am wondering how or if this could be argued in arbitrary dimension? I think the argument should work but I know geometry gets different in higher dimensions. For example in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the regular shape for $n=3$ would be a triangle but then for $n=4$ the shape would be a tetrahedron and not a square like in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But then for $n=5$ it is hard to visualize what that shape would look like.

My motivation is that I want to show that for any $n$ and any $d$, the $n$ points on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can all be positioned equidistant from each other. Then I want to come up with an expression for this distance in terms of $n$ and $d$. This is then my $K$.

How does this sound?

Comment: This is a well studied and in general difficult problem. Use *Spherical codes* as a buzzword to search more.

Comment: [Conway & Sloane](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-6568-7) is a classic reference here. I also want to mention the book by [Ericson & Zinoview](https://www.waterstones.com/book/codes-on-euclidean-spheres/thomas-ericson/victor-zinoviev/9780444503299).

Comment: If you have specific $d$ and $n$ in mind, then [Neil Sloane's database](http://neilsloane.com/packings/) is a good place to start.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks so much. I just googled spherical codes and yes this is exactly what I'm talking about. Super interesting. Haha, I thought there may be an existing solution to the problem!

Comment: maximizing minimum linear distance in $R^n$ for points on a sphere embedded in that space, should be equivalent to minimize the potential energy between repulsive  particles (electrons) ? I am not sure about ..

Comment: @GCab yes it seems this is mentioned on the wolfram page for spherical codes: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCode.html

Comment: good, then there is plenty of studies on the matter, e.g.[this](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath005/kmath005.htm)

Comment: It turns out this result published on the wolfram page seems to be exactly what I need. It is published there that for any $n$ points on the unit sphere, two of them must be a distance $d$ apart where $d \le \sqrt{4 - \csc^2(\frac{\pi n}{6(n-2)} )}$. This appears to scale with $1/\sqrt{n}$ which is very interesting for my problem. I am just a bit wary that this is only in 3 dimensions and not arbitrary dimension. I need to research more about it.